# parsing Json File with gson: MalformedJsonException

Tags: c#, json, parsing, exception, gson

I want to read a string which is formated like a JSON-File and print it on screen.
Therefore I am useing the GSON-Library.

Everytime I want to compile I get an **Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException** Error

My Code looks like this

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    String json = 
        "{"
                    + "'tag_name' : 'M mit Mbrunnen',"
                    + "'tag_id' : 'de_bw_xx_mstall',"
                    + "'tag_description': 'false',"
                    + "'tag_latitude': '42.704895',"
                    + "'tag_longitude': '10.652187',"
                    + "'tag_description_f_a': 'Ein weiteres Highlight in H',"
        + "}";

    // Now do the magic.
    Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);

    // Show it.
    System.out.println(data);
}
}

class Data {
private String tag_name;
private String tag_id;
private String tag_description;
private String tag_latitude;
private String tag_longitude;
private String tag_descrption_f_a;  

public String getName() { return tag_name; }
public String getId() { return tag_id; }
public String getDescription() { return tag_description; }
public String getLatitude() { return tag_latitude; }
public String getLongitude() { return tag_longitude; }
public String getDescriptionVoice() { return tag_descrption_f_a; }

public void setName(String name)                            { this.tag_name = name; }
public void setId(String id)                                { this.tag_id = id; }
public void setDescription(String description)              { this.tag_description = description; }
public void setLatitude(String latitude)                    { this.tag_latitude = latitude; }
public void setLongitude(String longitude)                  { this.tag_longitude = longitude; }
public void setDescriptionVoice(String descriptionVoice)    { this.tag_descrption_f_a = descriptionVoice; }

public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", tag_name, tag_id, tag_description, tag_latitude, tag_longitude, tag_descrption_f_a);
}
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 221
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:769)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:721)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:670)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:642)
>       at Test.main(Test.java:19)
>   Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected name at line 1 column 221
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1298)
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInObject(JsonReader.java:739)
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:382)
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:349)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:169)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:755)
>       ... 4 more

so the error happens here:

> ```
>     // Now do the magic.
>     Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);
> ```

I think my JSON-Data is provided in a wrong format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think your JSON in not well formed

it should be something like this

```
"{
    "tag_name": "M mit Mbrunnen",  // always use double quotes, single quote is not a valid json
    "tag_id": "de_bw_xx_mstall",
    "tag_description": "false",
    "tag_latitude": "42.704895",
    "tag_longitude": "10.652187",
    "tag_description_f_a": "Ein weiteres Highlight in H" // extra comma removed from here
}"
```

you can validate your JSON here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer and the validator-page!
Of course you always user " instead of ' but because the JSON is actually a String the usage of ' is right.

The error was here:
+ "'tag_description_f_a': 'Ein weiteres Highlight in H'-->,<--"

I just removed the comma and now it works ;)