# java.lang.IllegalStateException error message

Tags: java, json

I'm using Eclipse to covert json to a string in Java. But I keep getting the:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

error message each time I try to run my program. **Eclipse** doesn't recognize any errors/faults with my code. I've done some research and it seems that my json is not valid (I used `JSONLint`).

This is my json:

```
String json =     
 "{"
                +"'$type': 'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.RoadCorridor, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities',"
                + "'id' : a1,"
                + "'displayName' : 'A1',"
                + "'statusSeverity' : 'Good',"
                + "'statusSeverityDescription' : 'No Exceptional Delays',"
                + "'bounds' : '[[-0.25616,51.5319],[-0.10234,51.6562]]',"
                + "'envelope' : '[[-0.25616,51.5319],[-0.25616,51.6562],[-0.10234,51.6562],[-0.10234,51.5319],[-0.25616,51.5319]]',"
                + "'url' : 'https://api-argon.tfl.gov.uk/Road/a1'"
                + "}";
```

Please can someone tell me what is wrong with the json and how I can change it so its valid? I'm quite new to java and json so sorry if I missed out any details that I should have included.

Comment: Try using online json validators like http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [parsing Json File with gson: MalformedJsonException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073790/parsing-json-file-with-gson-malformedjsonexception)

Comment: @Joe It is technically a duplicate, but between the different languages and the different error messages, it's understandable that it wasn't found. This will be slightly more findable in the future for a similar group of people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using single quotes for your json identifiers. Use double-quotes.

```
"\"$type\": \"Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.RoadCorridor, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities\"," + etc.
```

The error is because your json code is malformed, those single quotes, while convenient in Java, are not valid for json.

Comment: I used this format for my json and now its valid on [link](www.jsonlint.com) and it also means my program works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You will oftern run into problems using single quotes instead of double quotes

```
 {
    "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.RoadCorridor, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
    "id": "a1",
    "displayName": "A1",
    "statusSeverity": "Good",
    "statusSeverityDescription": "No Exceptional Delays",
    "bounds": "[[-0.25616,51.5319],[-0.10234,51.6562]]",
    "envelope": "[[-0.25616,51.5319],[-0.25616,51.6562],[-0.10234,51.6562],[-0.10234,51.5319],[-0.25616,51.5319]]",
    "url": "https://api-argon.tfl.gov.uk/Road/a1"
 }
```

here is your json now valid, for reference i find that [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) is fantastic at helping debug invalid json

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use change it like below. There is a problem in handling of arrays.

```
{
'$type': {
    'Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.RoadCorridor, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities'
},
'id': a1,
'displayName': 'A1',
'statusSeverity': 'Good',
'statusSeverityDescription': 'No Exceptional Delays',
'bounds': '[[-0.25616,51.5319],[-0.10234,51.6562]]',
'envelope': '[[-0.25616,51.5319],[-0.25616,51.6562],[-0.10234,51.6562],[-0.10234,51.5319],[-0.25616,51.5319]]',
'url': 'https://api-argon.tfl.gov.uk/Road/a1'
```

}

refer here - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Comment: the brackets are meant to be quoted, since it's formatted as a java variable. You also probably want to make sure your file bracket gets included in the code block.